# Certificate Transparency, TLS Extension method of serving SCT's

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, certificate-transparency

I was curious about how to supply certificate transparency from my web server.
There are 3 ways certificate transparency information can be delivered to the client's browser (Source:
http://www.certificate-transparency.org/how-ct-works):

> 1. X.509v3 Extension (Embedded in the certificate)
> 2. OCSP Stapling (Signed, timestamped cached OCSP response, serving the SCT in OCSP extension)
> 3. TLS Extension (Doesn't require any action on part of the CA, server operator can submit standard certificate to CT log, and receive a SCT, and then deliver this SCT to client via TLS extension)

Here are screenshots of each example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrb1w.png

I am seeking resources, implementations of delivering SCT via TLS extension.

Comment: What webserver?

Apache can use the necessary `signed_certificate_timestamp` extension if you pass in the timestamp inside an `*.SCT` file.

See: https://ritter.vg/blog-require_certificate_transparency.html (Archived [here](https://archive.is/InXBT).)

Comment: Yeah apache or nginx, it is a bit painful to set up but its good that it can be done, I found the setup for nginx too if anyone else is looking.
https://sites.google.com/site/certificatetransparency/resources-for-site-owners/nginx